# Django: I have an object A with FK on B. How can I display the columns from B in a dropdown in the form of A?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, dropdown

I am getting the error "Unknown field(s) (topic, subject) specified for Session". I am trying to build a drop down for subject and topic in my sessionForm.

My model is below:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, primary_key = True)       

    def __str__(self):
      return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'subjects'  

class Module(models.Model):
  topic   = models.CharField(max_length = 200)  
  subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  

  def __str__(self):
    return self.topic + ' in ' + self.subject.name

  class Meta:
        db_table = 'modules'         

class Session(models.Model):
   grade_level  = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
   num_students = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   session_dt = models.DateTimeField() 
   module = models.ForeignKey(Module, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  @property
   def subject(self):
        return self.module.subject

   def topic(self):
        return self.module.topic   

   def __str__(self):
     return self.module.topic + ' on ' + self.session_dt

   class Meta:
        db_table = 'sessions'
```

My forms.py is

```
class SessionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Session      
        fields = ['subject', 'topic', 'session_dt', 'grade_level', 'num_students']
```

I am new to Django and Python. I already looked at Vitor Freitas article on Dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to override the init method of the ModelForm class and attach the desired fields to form fields, like:

```
class SessionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SessionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['subject'].queryset = Subject.objects.all()
        self.fields['topic'].queryset = Module.objects.none()

        if 'subject' in self.data: # This will be checked when you are saving the form via a POST method
            try:
                subject_id = int(self.data.get('subject'))
                self.fields['topic'].queryset = Module.objects.filter(subject_id=subject_id)
            except:
                # catch your errors here if the form contains invalid data
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['topic'].queryset = self.instance.subject.module_set


    class Meta:
        model = Session      
        fields = ['subject', 'topic', 'session_dt', 'grade_level', 'num_students']
```

I think having the `Subject` as the foreign key for `Session` makes more sense in your case as `Session` -> `Subject` -> `Module`.

Also, you will have to do an AJAX call when the dropdown value for the subject changes on your form. So create a separate view function, map it to a URL, and inside the function do this:

```
def load_modules(request):
    subject_id = request.GET.get('subject')
    modules = Modules.objects.get(id=subject_id)
    return render(request, `template name here`, {'modules': modules})
```

Comment: Adeel, thanks for your response. The Module already has "subject" and hence I am trying to not include subject in the Sessions to keep it truly relational. Can you please explain what the elif does in the init method?

Comment: The elif is for when you are updating an existing session object, so it has a primary key associated with it. Then it loads the related modules for the subject into the queryset for the topic field

Comment: I am still unable to get this to work, I have 2 problems. 1. I get 'ScoreForm' object has no attribute 'instance' error. 2. I see "Subject" in the drop down. When I select the subject I see the topic dropdown but the value is blanks. However, if I select a subject with no topic, I do not see the blank value. A few things have changes since I posted last. "Score" table has all scores for questions tested in a session. Session is FK in score. Module is FK in session and module has "subject" and "topic".

Comment: @Shanthi you are getting the `object has no attribute instance` error because you are inheriting the forms.Form class and not the forms.ModelForm class, as i had posted in my original answer. Also, i would request to add edits to the question, editing answers would make it confusing for me. :)

Comment: @Shanthi for the 2nd problem, you are doing a `values_list` of `module__topic` which will give you something like [('module__topic', `module id here`), ....]. You should do a `select_related` : x = Session.objects.filter(..).select_related('module'). Then in template you can do something equivalent of [(session.module.subject.id, session.module.subject.name) for session in x]. Also, i will revert the answer to the original one now

Comment: Adeel, my problem #1 seems to be resolved. For #2, I need only distinct topics that are active (status is in modules table) and related to the subject chosen in the earlier dropdown list. If I do select_related, I am getting all topics from the sessions table irrespective of the subject and status. I apologize for editing the answer, I thought I was updating my question.

Comment: @Shanthi you can chain the same filter statement with select_related. Neither of them has any effect on the other. I would just do: `Session.objects.select_related('module').filter(subject=subject, module__status='Active').order_by('module__topic')`

Comment: Adeel if I do that, I have an issue. I can have multiple "session" records for the same topic. Since the session ids are different for each of these topics, I get the same topic multiple times. Basically, I need to get the id and the topic name from the module table for those records available in the Session table. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: @Shanthi, your problem can be solved in many ways, like: a better database design or writing a raw query, `Topic.objects.raw(...)`, or doing a simple for loop over the results of the `select_related` query, and skipping topics which are already seen. The last option option is the simplest, though not the best, and will work ok as long as the result returned by the query is not huge. Also, I think this is a totally different problem than the original question asked.